# Out of the Woods Breakdown

Tags: meaning, taylor-swift

What are the presumably metaphorical "woods," in Taylor Swift's "[Out of the Woods](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JLf9q36UsBk)?" I think it refers to a jungle of memories or better yet, a jungle of discomfort which can be compared to her relationship with Harry Styles, but I'd appreciate a second opinion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider this quotation from a [Billboard article](https://www.billboard.com/articles/columns/pop/9327831/harry-styles-taylor-swift-songs-about-him#:%7E:text=Harry%20Styles%20Reveals%20He%20Played,Styles%20said%20it%20doesn%27t.) about a Howard Stern interview with Harry Styles (3 Mar 2020):

> Stern then brought up Styles' former romance with Taylor Swift, whose songs "Out of the Woods" and "Style" are widely believed to be about the One Direction member.

Also this quote from an NPR interview with Taylor Swift (quoted by [Showbiz CheatSheet](https://www.cheatsheet.com/entertainment/taylor-swift-most-popular-songs-harry-styles.html/)):

> “‘Hit the brakes too soon’ could mean…we got in an accident and we had to deal with the aftermath. But also, the relationship ended sooner than it should’ve because there was a lot of fear involved,” she said. Swift adds that there was “a huge sense of anxiety” involved and a lot of media attention.

These both support your idea.